# Maven Build using WebApplicationInitializer instead of web.xml

Tags: java, maven, querydsl, spring-java-config

I have run into sort of a problem. I am using all Java based configuration, minus logback.xml because I did not find a good example showing how that could be configured without XML.

Anyway my issue is when I do

```
mvn clean build
```

It fails because it can't find web.xml. This is an issue because I'm using QueryDSL which has a Maven plugin to generate the classes it needs. So I need to be able to do a Maven build without a web.xml or I need to be able to generate the QueryDSL meta classes without Maven.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>igdb</finalName>
    </build>
```

My web.xml was replaced by this code.

```
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        /**
         * If no active profile is set via -Dspring.profiles.active then the application
         * will default to development mode
         */
         container.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.default", "dev");

        /**
         * create the root Spring application context
         */
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.setDisplayName("IGDb");
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        /**
         * manage the lifecycle of the root application context
         */
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        /**
         * register and map the dispatcher servlet
         */
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.1</version>
 <configuration>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```